# Issue while call BEFORE trigger on postgresql

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, triggers, plpgsql

i have a jdbc client communicate with a postgresql database. From JDBC a create a prepared statement for INSERT some data on a table, but at the moment of the creation of query, client doesn't know all field to insert inside statement, and for complete the query i've write a TRIGGER that fires BEFORE insert on that table, find the missing value, the continue to execute query.
this is jdbc code:

```
String MY_INSERT = "INSERT INTO myTable VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement pstm = connection.PrepareStatement(MY_INSERT);
pstm5.setInt(1, 2562);
pstm5.setInt(2, 22);
pstm5.setInt(3, 0); //unknown value, set to zero
pstm5.setString(4, "a string");
pstm5.setInt(5, 0); //the other unknown value
```

this is the trigger code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION perform_() RETURNS trigger AS $myTrigger$

DECLARE 
vend VARCHAR(20);
pre numeric(10,2);

BEGIN
    SELECT field3, field5 FROM otherTable WHERE id = NEW.field2 INTO vend, pre;

    NEW.field3 = vend;
    NEW.field5 = pre;

    RETURN NULL;
END;
$myTrigger$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger
BEFORE INSERT ON myTable
EXECUTE PROCEDURE perform_();
```

when the trigger fires i have this error:

```
Exception: JDBCClass error: ERROR: record "new" is not assigned yet
Details: The tuple structure of a not-yet-assigned record is indeterminate.
SELECT field3, field5 FROM otherTable WHERE id = NEW.field2 INTO vend, pre;
```

what does it mean? record new it's assigned as you can see into jdbc code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you've missed `FOR EACH ROW` in trigger declaration:

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger
BEFORE INSERT ON myTable
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE perform_();
```

Second, you have to `return NEW;` if you want your record to be inserted into your table

see [**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/4cb5c/2)